# How to Use "sed" Bash Command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am having difficulties replacing a string in c program file with the content of a variable in a bash file. The idea is to copy the address of Linux kernel sys_call_table and then use it in my C program to intercept system calls. I found a couple of examples online, but none of them have worked for me so far. So any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the content of my bash file, "bashFile.sh"

```
    TABLE=$(grep sys_call_table /boot/System.map-$(uname -r) |awk '{print $1}')
    sed -i "s/myTABLE/{$TABLE}/g" my_LKM.c
```

When I run "sudo sh bashFile.sh" command, nothing happen. The string myTable in C file does not get replaced. However, when I try the following variation:

```
    TABLE=$(grep sys_call_table /boot/System.map-$(uname -r) |awk '{print $1}')
    sed -i 's/myTABLE/{$TABLE}/g' my_LKM.c
```

the myTABLE string get replaced with {$TABLE} instead of the content of the variable TABLE (sys_call_table address). I tried debugging with "echo $TABLE" to see if TABLE content is the address of sys_call_table and it worked. So, I concluded that the problem might be the syntax of sed command. However, I do not know how to fix it at this time. Thank you in advance for your help.

P.S. Below is the content of myLKM.c file:

```
    unsigned long *sys_call_table;  
    sys_call_table = (unsigned long *)myTABLE;
```

Comment: Better give us an example of what's in your `$TABLE`. Probably contains some metacharacter in it. By the way, your second "variation" doesn't make sense because no parameter expansion is performed within single quotes.

Comment: This question is not directly related to the c programming language, the file you want to edit is a text file for what it matters.

Comment: @iharob did you see a text file somewhere? myLKM.c is not a text file. As I explained above, the content of $TABLE variable is the memory address of the "sys_call_table" data structure (see Linux Kernel). I tried the second variation because it was suggested by somebody online. Thank you for your time.

Comment: So it's a binary file?

Comment: why are you using `sudo` to run a command that's modifying `my_LKM.c`?  Surely your normal account has write permission on the file you're working on.  Also, you don't need `grep | awk`, you could just use the grep pattern as a `/pattern/ {print $1}` in awk.

Comment: I assume you're executing your `bash` code in the same dir that contains your file `my_LKM.c`? Maybe you want to put a `cd /path/to/file` and `echo $PWD` before executing that code? (Just an idea). Good luck

Comment: Did you check your filename? You state the sed to my_LKM.c yet the example data is for the file myLKM.c without an underbar.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use `sudo` to run this.  It doesn't magically make things work.  If you need root privileges to edit source code you're working on, you have serious problems with your development setup.

---

Use **double-quotes** if you want stuff to expand inside them.  e.g.

```
TABLE=$(awk '/sys_call_table/ {print $1}' /boot/System.map-$(uname -r))
sed -i "s/myTABLE/${TABLE}UL/g" my_LKM.c
```

As karakfa suggested, make sure you try this without `-i` first.  His other suggestion, of expanding `$TABLE` in an unquoted context, instead of inside double quotes, was terrible, though.  You need the entire string to be part of the same `sed` arg, so just ending the single quotes is bad.

Also, I guess he misread `{$TABLE}` for `${TABLE}`, and simplified to `$TABLE`.  Or actually, from the context of your question, it looks like you want a plain numeric constant, not wrapped in braces.  So you should use `$TABLE`.

Actually, you should use `${TABLE}UL` so it's an unsigned-long integer literal.  Without those modifiers, an address that didn't fit in the low32 would probably get mangled before the cast to a pointer type was applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes

```
sed -i 's/myTABLE/'$TABLE'/g' my_LKM.c
```

obviously try first NOT in-place (remove `-i`)

Comment: Basically no different than `sed -i "s/myTABLE/$TABLE/g" my_LKM.c`, except word splitting and filename expansion are performed on unquoted `$TABLE`, which makes it even worse.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately it did not work.